# How do I pass values to an array without creating variables?

Tags: java

```
public static void testArray(int[]a)
{
    for(int i:a)
    {

        if(i==10)
        {
        System.out.println("Number 10 exists !");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to pass parameters to this method without creating variables. I want to call it like so:

```
testArray({5, 10, 15});
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void testArray(int ... a)
{ 
    for(int i:a)
        if(i==10)
            System.out.println("Number 10 exists !");
}

testArray(5, 10, 15);
```

Comment: Whaaat !?   "int ... a" are you sure?

Comment: It is "Variable Arguments" http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

Comment: This answer should point out that this is only viable for the *last* method argument.

Answer (score 8):

```
testArray(new int[]{5, 10, 15});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
testArray(new int[] {1,2,3,4});
```